# Show that $A^2 = 0$ iff $\operatorname{im}(\alpha) \subset \ker(\alpha)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

I am tasked to solve the following problem.

Let $A \in M_2(K)$ be a certain "fixed" matrix and $\alpha : M_2(K) \rightarrow M_2(K)$ be a map defined by: $\alpha(M)= A \cdot M$ for all $M \in M_2(K)$. I have already shown that $\alpha$ is linear and that if $A$ is invertible, then $\alpha$ is invertible.

I now have to show that $A^2 = 0$ iff $\operatorname{im}(\alpha) \subset \ker(\alpha)$ and I dont have any idea how to do that. I am a newbie to linear algebra, and I am unfortunately pretty weak on proofs, so any hints/ suggestions would be appreciated.

P.S. I have also found the matrix of $\alpha$ in the canonical basis of $M_2(K)$ which I think is this:
$$\begin{bmatrix}a & 0 & b & 0\\0 & a & 0 & b \\ c & 0 & d & 0\\ 0 & c & 0 & d \\\end{bmatrix}$$

Given that $A= \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d 
\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really just asked to play with the definitions of $\textrm{im}(A)$ and $\ker(A)$.

If $\textrm{im}(A)\subseteq\textrm{ker}(A)$, it should be obvious that $A^2=0$. Indeed, for all column vector $X$, $AX\in\ker(A)$, which means $A(AX)=0$, namely $A^2X=0$.

If $A^2=0$, let $X\in\textrm{im}(A)$, there exists a column vector $Y$ such that $X=AY$. Left-multiplying this identity by $A$ leads to $AX=A^2Y$, but since $A^2=0$, if follows that $AX=0$, namely $X\in\ker(A)$.

In a similar fashion, can you adapt the above proof to show the following statement?

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two square matrices of the same size, then $AB=0$ if and only if $\textrm{im}(B)\subseteq\ker(A)$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: A similar proof can be written, not using at all the fact that you're dealing with matrices. The advantage of this approach is that the very same proof can be applied at various algebraic contexts, wherever $ker, im$, etc., can be reasonably defined.